# Get this as HTMLelement in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'd like to get THIS as HTMLelement so I can get its id, innerHTML etc.. However react returns the whole React.Component.

**WHAT I WANT**

```html
<button onclick="document.write('this.innerHTML : '+this.innerHTML)">Click me</button>
```

**React Code**

```
<button onClick={()=> console.log(this.innerHTML)}>CLICK ME!</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use ref attribute(like ref='btn1') on button element and in React Component access to it by this.refs.btn1.

Check this link [link](http://jamesknelson.com/react-js-by-example-interacting-with-the-dom/)

Comment: Ok I Guess I'm gonna have to use it, but id rather not use any refs... thx